# SFML trouble if(font.loadFromFile(FONT_PATH)) -> expected declaration

Tags: sfml

sf::Font font
const std::string FONT_PATH = "$(SolutionDir)\resources\Fonts\Oswald-Regular.ttf";
if (!font.loadFromFile(FONT_PATH))
return -1;
...

There is an error with the if statement. It expects a decleration. I honestly dont know why its not working since the rest is working

Honestly, did not try that much since everything else works, so my libs and includes are in the right place and implemented correctly. Im using VS 2022.